# Oracle SQL Developer find specific data from databse

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to only select the data which only D LineType with a single document from the database. I have 2 tables in the database and it should link with another table. Below is my codes:

```
SELECT ID, DOC, LNTY
FROM Table1
WHERE LNTY='DF'
UNION 
SELECT ID, DOC, LNTY
FROM Table2 
WHERE LNTY='DF'
```

My Database:

```
Table 1
Doc     LNTY
001     D
001     B
002     B
002     D
003     S
004     D
005     B
006     D

Table 2
Doc     LNTY
004     B
007     D
007     B
008     D
```

Expected Output:

```
Doc     LNTY
006     D
008     D
```

My codes didn't work because it will show all the D LineType rather than a single document with only one D LineType. Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: How do you determine which Doc to return if there are 6 D rows?

Comment: My expected output will be like only 1 D LineType with a single respective Doc and Doc is not a unique key so it can be repeated.

Comment: There are several ways to get your expected output from that data, so can you clarify your rules? Do you want the 'last' (however that is defined) row/doc from each table which has a D (even if it has other line types too; and what if the 'last' row isn't D)? Or all docs which only have a D and no other line types, across both tables? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `UNION ALL` :

```
select Doc, min(LNTY)
from table1 t1
group by Doc
having min(LNTY) = max(LNTY) and min(LNTY) = 'D'
union all
select Doc, min(LNTY)
from table2 t2
group by Doc
having min(LNTY) = max(LNTY) and min(LNTY) = 'D';
```

I think this code has oveflowed with two `group by`s, so i just reduce it to reflect the below conversations :

```
select Doc, min(LNTY) LNTY
from (select Doc, LNTY
      from table1 t1
      union all
      select Doc, LNTY
      from table2 t2
     ) t
group by Doc
having min(LNTY) = max(LNTY) and min(LNTY) = 'D';
```

Comment: You may want to union then group, otherwise `004 D` will return.  (`004 B` is in the second table)

Comment: Currently, it worked fine for me, can you explain this `having min(LNTY) = max(LNTY) and min(LNTY) = 'D'` how it worked, wanted to know its logic before applying into my work.

Comment: @RogerT - that part is checking there is a single `LNTY` for the doc - because if there was more than one, the min and max would be different; and that the min (or max, doesn't matter) is D, which is the filter you want to apply overall. But Aaron raises an interesting point; and is the doc/line type combination unique (even across both tables?), and if not would you want to include a doc that had two Ds?

Comment: @AlexPoole It is just my sample data, but in logically it is possible that same doc with another D LineType data since it didn't share the same primary key across both tables.

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you're looking for you could use:

```
SELECT MAX(DOC) AS DOC, 'D' AS LNTY
  FROM TABLE_1
  WHERE LNTY = 'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(DOC) AS DOC, 'D' AS LNTY
  FROM TABLE2
  WHERE LNTY = 'D'
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/588fa3/2)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **rownum** for it this will surely work:-

```
create table ns_table1(
doc varchar(10),
lnty varchar(10));

create table ns_table2(
doc varchar(10),
lnty varchar(10));

insert into ns_table1 values('001','D');
insert into ns_table1 values('001','B');
insert into ns_table1 values('002','B');
insert into ns_table1 values('002','D');
insert into ns_table1 values('003','S');
insert into ns_table1 values('004','D');
insert into ns_table1 values('005','B');
insert into ns_table1 values('006','D');

insert into ns_table2 values('004','B');
insert into ns_table2 values('007','D');
insert into ns_table2 values('007','B');
insert into ns_table2 values('008','D');



select * from ns_table1 where rownum<=8 minus select * from ns_table1 where rownum<=7 union all  
select * from ns_table2 where rownum<=4 minus select * from ns_table2 where rownum<=3;
```

Comment: @Alex Poole check you discarded my previous answer that is why tagged you

Comment: Well, it gets the same output the OP showed, but as with Bob's answer I think not for the right reasons. You seem to be assuming they want the 'last' D entry from each table, but I think they want those that *only* have a D, and it's coincidence they're shown last in the output in the sample data. But anyway, using rownum without an order-by clause is indeterminate, and if you know the criteria to say which is 'last' then there are other ways to get that single row, which don't rely on knowing and hard-coding how many rows there are. But we'll see what RogerT thinks.

Comment: @alex poole it depends. for other such as B we will use other query.although i agree i  have hardcoded it but its giving the answers there is no other possible solution to it